# Django: saving dynamic formfields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

first of all sorry for the question because I'm a newbie and english is not my native language (feel free to ask if the post needs editing).

I am following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563475/how-to-loop-through-form-fields-and-store-them-all-in-the-database) to save forms dynamically but you can only do that with one field and now I am trying to duplicate 3 fields at once(success) and the saving one field (tested it with only one field) is not a problem thanks to the thread mentioned above.

But the problem starts when there are 2 or more fields in my forms.py, it always say

```
The ModelName could not be created because the data didn't validate
```

and points to my `form.save()`

I'm out of ideas on how resolve my problem and any suggestion, link, or even a sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class aform(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = boom
        fields = ('a', 'b', 'c',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(aform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['a'].widget.attrs.update({'id': '0', 'name':'a',})
        self.fields['b'].widget.attrs.update({'id': '1','name':'a',})
```

my views

```
def index(request):
    form = aform(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            for name in request.POST.getlist('a'):
                catform = aform({'a': name}, instance=boom())
                catform.save()
```

Comment: Why aren't you using formsets?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up

Comment: Really thank full. Solved every problem I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman said, why not use formsets?

As a beginner i really have no idea that it exists and started digging around and found some neat things like elo80ka's [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) which really solves every single problem I have (Cheers to him) [this](https://godjango.com/9-forms-part-4-formsets/) tutorial really helped big time.